# Android Animation Doesn't Work on first run

Tags: android, animation

So this is the issue.
Animation at first run doesn't work, I have no idea why.
At first I used an xml for animation, but in that way animation worked only on first try and never again, so I changed and make everything in java code..
But now, well it always runs except on first try.
Have to clear up that I have to work on a 2.2 (froyo) version.

```
public class HomePage extends Activity {
protected View menu;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page_portrait);
    ImageButton plus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    menu = (View) findViewById(R.id.layoutmenu);
    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //menu.clearAnimation();
            Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,-menu.getWidth(),0,0);
            menu.clearAnimation();
            if(menu.isShown()) {
                animation.setDuration(500);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                menu.setAnimation(animation);
                menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
            }
            else {
                animation.reset();
                animation = new TranslateAnimation(-menu.getWidth(),0,0,0);
                animation.setDuration(500);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                menu.setAnimation(animation);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Any clues?

**EDIT**
So I've changed my code but now doesn't work at all.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
            //menu.clearAnimation();
            Animation animation;
            menu.clearAnimation();
            if(menu.isShown()) {
                //animation.reset();
                animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,-menu.getWidth(),0,0);
                animation.setDuration(500);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                });
                menu.setAnimation(animation);
                menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
            }
            else {
                //animation.reset();
                animation = new TranslateAnimation(-menu.getWidth(),0,0,0);
                animation.setDuration(500);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                });
                menu.setAnimation(animation);
                //menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            animation.reset();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below line.

```
menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Instead of making the visibility to GONE here, add a **`AnimationListener`** to **`animation`** and in the listener, `onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)` method make your view visibility to GONE.

This will take care to change the visibility of a view to GONE after the whole animation got completed.

Comment: Oh well.. Changed.. but doesn't work at all. Any idea? [New code post]

Comment: Remove the line  menu.setVisibility(View.GONE); which is out side the Listener.